# "Mask" Route react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

For example, I have two routes:

```
<IndexRoute component={Index} />
<Route path="/categories/:slug" component={CatFilter} />
```

Then in my navigation component I have:

```
  <nav className="nav-main">
    <ul>
      <li><IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Work</IndexLink></li>
      <li><Link to="/posts" activeClassName="active">Blog</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/resume" activeClassName="active">Resume</Link></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Is there any way to accomplish having the IndexLink in the nav component receive the active class when I'm on the root page and a `/categories/:slug` page?

It's my understanding that defining an IndexLink strictly connects it to the root, if this is accurate, is there a different way to go about it?

I'm new to react-router but I've read through numerous issues on the Github repository and I can't seem to find anyone having a similar issue. This leads me to believe that's I might be setting up my route structure incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `<Link className={location.pathname.includes('/categories') ? 'active' : ''} />` something like that?

Comment: thanks - that worked!